# Applying formulas on cells in separate Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula

I have two different Google spreadsheets (these are separate files). I would like to calculate the sum of two cells (say A1) in the first and second spreadsheet/file and have it show up in a third/new spreadsheet/file. Is this possible and how might one go about doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the IMPORTRANGE formula, which is ("URL of other sheet","range of cells you want to import").

Make sure both parts of the formula have " around them, so that the formula in the 3rd sheet would be something like:

=IMPORTRANGE("Sheet1Key","Sheet1!A1")+IMPORTRANGE("Sheet2Key","Sheet1!A1")